# CodeIgniter- CSS & JS are not loading when the site is run on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter and the MVC architecture but i know PHP very well. Here is the problem I am facing:

I downloaded the source code of the live website via cpanel (the site is developed on codeignitor) and now I am trying to modifying the site on Localhost.

I need to change the styling of the pages but I can't get the site to load it's CSS & JS on localhost environment, only the html is being loaded.
I've checked various configurations and environment settings.
In config file I changed `$config['base_url']= "http://localhost/sitename/"` for localhost and other config variables are already set (since i downloaded the source code).

Now when i run the site on localhost with url `http://localhost/sitename/` , only the html is loaded without any styling, css/js nothing!

I also noticed the following : (thought it maybe useful)

in files like `header.php` and `footer.php` the CSS & JS files are included like this `<link href = "<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>/css/main.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"/>` and `<script src="<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>/js/main.js"></script>`.

Whereas in fact the css and js files are actually present in `root\assets\css\` and `root\assets\js\`

So,

1. How should I view the complete site (as it was online, with all the css & js) on the localhost? Are there any settings or scripts that i need to change?
2. How was it actually working on the live website? (with wrong paths set for access to CSS & JS)

Help. Thanks! (Do let me know if I need to furnish more details)

Comment: Where did you get `WEB_ROOT` and what is `src="<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>/css/main.css"` giving you?  You need to use your browser to **inspect the live DOM** to see what URL is being inserted into the file includes for the CSS and JavaScript.  Once you see these, you'll have a better chance of knowing what settings to change in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Reading the manual wouldn't hurt either:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

Comment: It's actually `href=".."` with a link tag instead of src. Typo, my bad! I wrote only the href part to focus the attention on the path and the `WEB_ROOT` constant (which now turns out is nothing, as you and others say).

Comment: Anyway, yes I think I need to read the manual cuz I don't understand a single thing in and around this. I was just hoping to get a quick and easy solution instead of learning the whole codeigniter since my main goal was just to modify the CSS & JS for mobile compatibility. But clearly I can't get away without it! Can I?

Comment: I also inspected the live DOM and found that all the scripts & stylesheets are are getting a 404 not found. That obviously shows there's something wrong with the paths they are fetched from. I couldn't understand one thing though, I directly downloaded the whole source code from the live website which is working absolutely fine, but when i run it on the localhost, the code changes? "_"

Comment: It only takes a few hours to read the entire CodeIgniter manual including the tutorial.  It's not that difficult or time-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things:

Make sure apache has `rewrite_mode` on  and `.htaccess` file is at the correct location.

In config.php file:

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourappfoldername/';
```

In controller:

```
  public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('url'));

    //======== or simply ===============

    $this->load->helper('url');

}
```

your css and js url:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/assets/css/styleshee.css');?>">
```

If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the index.php page set this variable blank:

```
  $config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess file (remove index.php):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
 </IfModule>
```

Change your routes as according without the `index.php` page.  If index.php is removed:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo  base_url('/assets/css/styleshee.css');?>">
```

Comment: You could also put the URL Helper into the `autoload.php` file.  And please do not post answers as one giant code block.  Code goes within code blocks; everything else does not.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your css and images etc are out side of application folder

```
project > application

project > assets >

project > assets > css

project > assets > images

project > assets > js
```

Then autoload url helper. `$this->load->helper('url');`

Then

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/styleshee.css');?>">
```

As you have done set the base url

```
$config['base_url']= "http://localhost/sitename/";
```

You may need to include index.php if you are not using `.htaccess` to create pretty URLs.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/assets/css/styleshee.css');?>">
```

Comment: The CSS & similar folders are already outside the application folder (inside assets, as you have described). Also, .htaccess is already in use for URL rewritting. I tried the `base_url()` function but it gave an error `call to undefined function base_url()`

Comment: And could you tell me where to add the autoload url helper? In the the `autoload.php` m guessing?

Comment: config/autoload.php you should read user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=autoload

Comment: Its a bit strange when I was first to answer and few other people got up voted but I did not.

Answer (score 1):

The constant `WEB_ROOT` is not part of the Codeigniter framework. So the first thing to do is find the definition and change it so it matches the localhost domain. It is probably defined as the specific live domain. Obviously the localhost is some other domain.

Alternatively, do what @wolfgang1983 says in his answer. (Which was posted while I was writing this and is what I was going to say.)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=<?php echo base_url('assets/css/main.css'); ?> />
```

Then when your assets aren't loading, you can troubleshoot it in your web browser. You can do this by clicking inspect > network. Then refresh your page and see where codeigniter is trying to read the files from. If it isn't correct, you can usually see whats going wrong. (for example I once had that my assets were being loaded from: `localhost/localhost/assets/*/*` 
I hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create new folder and named it as you own. I created new folder call "assets". Then it placed inside project folder like as below picture. [image of the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJhaR.png)

Then i changed config.php file base url path. [image of the changed config.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C9l7.png)

After that i added new new helper in controller class. [Image of the changed controller class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXIfK.png)

Finally i link style sheet like as below image.